# I tried to make my ubuntu 12.10 boot faster using the following link's instructions.It crashed my unity launcher and menu bar .How do i fix this.

Tags: unity, grub2, 12.10

[This was the site from which i made changes](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/01/how-to-increasespeed-up-ubuntu-booting.html)

I have tried to install unity-reset,didn't help.When i log in,only the mouse functions showing only the desktop.Yet,i can still run my terminal through shortcuts.
I have the live CD can i restore it to the original point ??
Thanks for your time.Hope to see an answer very soon.

Comment: Wow. From what I know the trick mentioned in this article is not gaining any boot-up speed since few years.

Comment: boot speed did increase a lot.from what i learnt now i suspect it never loads the os itself.

Comment: Oh, it's probably not loading Unity at all, even that will result in some boot-up boost.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that link just screws with your grub configuration... so reloading it with the live disk should 'theoretically' fix it if that is the problem.

See [Ubuntu's guide for how to recover grub with the live disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows), it's meant for being done after installing windows but basically does what you want in this case.